# The exact definition of the Lab frame

Tags: special-relativity, particle-physics, kinematics, reference-frames, collision

What is the exact definition of the lab frame? In most textbooks, the ‘lab frame’ is taken to be that in which one of the particles is initially at rest. Can we define a 'lab frame' for example, in which two ultrarelativistic particles of different energy and different momenta collide in opposite directions?

Answer (score 3):

"Lab" just stands for laboratory, i.e. it's the frame of the room in which the experiment is performed. For example, in the LHC's "lab frame" the protons come in head-on, back to back.

Comment: head on head? :)